# Elements of Statistical Learning - Statistical Decision Theory : formula 2.10 EPE

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

Recently, I have been reading the 《Elements of Statistical Learning》book . Now,I have three question in chapter 2 formula(2.10).
(1)What does $pr(dx,dy)$ in Formula 2.10 mean?

(2)how to derivate this (2.10)formula?

(3)Can $pr(dx,dy)$ be written as $pr(x,y)dxdy$？

The ESL book (2.10):
$EPE(f)=\int[y-f(x)]^2Pr(dx,dy)$

can modify(2.10) to the formula belows?:
$EPE(f)=\int[y-f(x)]^2Pr(x,y)dxdy$

the formula (2.10) context content in book is as below picture:

[image]

Comment: To get an answer, consider quoting the formula and the context in which it is stated directly into your question.

Comment: I have added the context,Thank you for your reminder.,